# How to have multiple aliases for a controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a Search controller with a generic Search() action that takes several parameters and has a bunch of logic. I'd like to call this from other controllers without having a lot of copy/paste code.

I'd like to call this action from these different urls/controllers.actions.

`/Search/Search?text=mySearchText
 /User/SearchTransactions?type=purcahse
 /Transactions/UserSearch?UserId=1`

I could move the method to a baseController but I'd have to call /Search on each controller and I'd like to have them all named differently.

Comment: Is all of your logic actually in your generic "search" action?  If so, I would highly recommend you move that logic out to a different class that you can then call from *any* controller/action in your solution.   I don't see a reason to hack the MVC routing when it should be a line or two to a shared method to do the searching.

Comment: @Tommy I tried that but I have a bunch of logic that also adds to the viewbag and other context related stuff that became a mess trying to pass in to that class method vs the action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you already have your solution man put it in base controller and decorate it with actionName attribute

like

```
    [ActionName("Search1")]
    public ActionResult SearchText(string text) {
        return View();
    }

  [ActionName("Search2")]
    public ActionResult SearchType(string Type) {
        return View();
    }

  [ActionName("Search3")]
    public ActionResult searchId(int ID) {
        return View();
    }
```

now you can do like

```
/search1
/search2
/search3
```

Comment: There is only one actual Search() action I'd like to use and I can't use multiple ActionName attributes that I know of

Comment: @user3953989 so basically you want to call 1 action with 3 different names

Comment: i really dont think that gonnahappen man although you can do a redirect to action hack which i guess you  can do check my second answer

Comment: I tried using View("../Search/Search", model) in each and that keeps the url correct but the model doesn't handle the querystring params

Comment: @user3953989 whats the issue with model it should have work though

Comment: The model is a list of searchResults, it doesn't include what was needed to get those results